# How to archive drupal forums?

Tags: 7, nodes

How can I add archive state to drupal forums so that:

> - They are not visible in search results
> - They are shown in a different container
> - They are visible only to some users based on user-roles

I don't want to unpublish them-

I also want a spam state to differentiate unpublished and spam posts

Comment: Sorry, i misread "forum" for "form" and I tought you were meaning "webform" module.. sorry!

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

- They are not visible in search results

http://drupal.org/project/search_config

- They are shown in a different container

Templating system, or blocks, or panels

- They are visible only to some users based on user-roles

**EDIT**

Those 2 steps are equal, but becose my understanding problem the last point can be different.

In `/admin/people/permissions` you should have the options to allow only some roles to access the forms nodes.

Comment: I am still confused, what would be the state of forum topic and webform funda?

Comment: ooops sorry my bad, i misread "forum" for "form"..